# Hook Function to Footer

Tags: hooks

I would like to know how to hook a function in the footer area right before the `</body>` tag. The function would produce html.

```
function html_footer(){
    does stuff
}
places_in_footer('html_footer()');
```

I've done some research on the subject but it seems like there are a lot of different methods but all of them are deprecated. So I'm not sure what the right method would be.

For example in wordpress it would be:

```
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create one block and add the html content and place this block in the footer region. This content will place inside the  tag and after the main content. Thats mean you will get your content before the closing  tag.

Comment: I have a function generating the HTML so its not static. i need some way of hooking the function to the footer.

Comment: If you generating the html from from a function, why can't you make this function as block and place the block in the footer region. You will get option to disable and enable the block, also you will get more options to control the block. If you don't want to use block, then you can make use of  hook_page_build like this - `function hook_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['page_bottom'] = array(
    '#markup' => your_html_content(),
  );
}`